# JAVA Spring batch - JmsItemReader

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-batch, spring-jms

I am working on a Spring Batch application, I have to receive a JMS file and read it (the JMS queue contains a JSON message), then convert the message into a POJO arrayList . I want to use the `JmsItemReader` with a `MappingJackson2MessageConverter`, but all the examples of the configuration on the internet are in annotation and while I have an xml configuration and I need to do it in xml too.

Does anyone have an example of xml configuration? I need your help. PS: Here is the documentation I'm trying to follow: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/batch/spring-batch-jmsitemreader-example/

Comment: What have you tried?  What is missing from the documentation?

Comment: i try to receive JMS queue and convert message to an ArrayList<Object> with JmsItemReader  to read the JMS and MappingJackson2MessageConverter  to convert message. My configuration file is in xml but the documentation https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/batch/spring-batch-jmsitemreader-example/ is in annotation?? how can i do this in xml ? and can i convert my jms message to  ArrayList<Object>?